# Can I POST to Authorize.net like you can with PayPal?

Tags: forms, paypal, authorize.net

Im using simpleCart.js to build a simple, low-trafic, low product count, shopping cart. It's default is PayPal. Upon checkout, it sends you to PayPal.com with a few simple values... Product description, quantity and total. You see this sort of checkout all over the place.

simpleCart.js also supports a `SendForm` function which, is basically a form POST directed to a URL of your choice. My question is, can such a form POST be submitted directly to Authorize.net, as you would with PayPal?

The author says he was able to use simpleCart.js w/SendForm to work with Authorize.net, but I can't help but think that this means through a view on his own site, which is then processed with PHP, Python, whatever. At which point the interaction between my site and Authorize.net is via an SDK, and not a direct POST.

Any tips? Im using Django, so I can build out a view and then use Paython or something to connect to Authorize.net, but I would like to NOT have a CC form on my site. I want exactly what PayPal gives me, only I want it with Authorize.net.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On http://developer.authorize.net/guides/SIM/, see

- **Section Three -> Transaction Post Location** and
- **Section Three -> Requesting the Secure Hosted Payment Form**.

That will show you where your form must submit to and what inputs it needs in order to use Authorize.net's SIM.

Haven't used simpleCart.js, so I can't be of more help... but hope that gets you in the right direction.

Comment: Simply knowing that this can be accomplished and that the SIM method is the way to do it is more than enough for me to get everything connected. Thank you for pointing me to this.